# Trigger Cloud Function based on Firestore changes (Python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Whenever there is change(created, modified, removed) in any document for a particular collection in Firestore, i want to capture the delta and publish it to pubsub.

I am trying all this in python.

Code Snippet :

```
ref = db.collection('country').document(city_id)
ref.update(body_json)
ref.on_snapshot(callback)

def callback(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for change in changes:
        if change.type.name == 'ADDED':
            print('ADDED')
        elif change.type.name == 'MODIFIED':
            print('MODIFIED')
        elif change.type.name == 'REMOVED':
            print('REMOVED')
    print('end of callback')
```

Now, when i make changes in the  firestore document, like :

1. Add new document - I get the print as **ADDED** and **end of callback**.
2. Modify existing document - I mostly get the print as **ADDED** but sometimes or rather once in 10 runs i get both **ADDED** and **MODIFIED**. followed by **end of callback**.
3. Remove any document - **end of callback**. Sometimes(rarely) both **REMOVED** and **end of callback**.

I am unable to understand this behaviour and don't know how to deal  with this unable print executions.

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions) yet?

Comment: yes but its in nodejs

Comment: [This](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#functions_firebase_firestore-python) documentation could be helpful in your case. That, in combination with Dan's (even though it is in NodeJS) may help you approach your issue right.

Answer (score 0):

*The limitation is this is Node.js only, so Javascript only. I think it still applies and is worth you looking into, so sharing it here as despite your question being Python based it's the best option.*

I think Cloud Functions would be great for you here. You can set triggers that will run functions on each of the things you've noted.

Added can be handled by onCreate.
Modified can be handled by onUpdate.
Removed - by onDelete.

You basically set up functions that look like this:

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      // Get an object representing the document
      // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
      const newValue = change.after.data();

      // ...or the previous value before this update
      const previousValue = change.before.data();

      // access a particular field as you would any JS property
      const name = newValue.name;

      // perform desired operations ...
    });
```

You're given the before and after states of the document for the example above, so you'll be able to not just know it was changed but what was changed.

The example code was straight from the documentation for Cloud Functions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated).